# calculate moment of inertia using components on 3 axis

Tags: solidworks

I have some geometric shapes that modeled on Solidworks, and it shows me the moment of inertia taken at the center of the mass, my question is can I use these information (Px,Py,Pz) to calculate the total moment of inertia around some axis ?

Solidworks result like this

```
Center of mass: ( millimeters )
    X = -3.07
    Y = 2.41
    Z = 4.00

Principal axes of inertia and principal moments of inertia: ( grams *  square millimeters )
Taken at the center of mass.
     Ix = ( 1.00,  0.00,  0.00)     Px = 675.07
     Iy = ( 0.00,  1.00,  0.00)     Py = 2557.45
     Iz = ( 0.00,  0.00,  1.00)     Pz = 3111.07

Moments of inertia: ( grams *  square millimeters )
Taken at the center of mass and aligned with the output coordinate system.
    Lxx = 675.07    Lxy = 0.00  Lxz = 0.00
    Lyx = 0.00  Lyy = 2557.45   Lyz = 0.00
    Lzx = 0.00  Lzy = 0.00  Lzz = 3111.07

Moments of inertia: ( grams *  square millimeters )
Taken at the output coordinate system.
    Ixx = 923.41    Ixy = -84.13    Ixz = -139.59
    Iyx = -84.13    Iyy = 2846.59   Iyz = 109.79
    Izx = -139.59   Izy = 109.79    Izz = 3284.21
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need the following two for the generic solution

- Parallel axis Theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem
- Rotation of the inertia tensor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Inertia_tensor_of_rotation

Given the Moment of inertia with respect to the center of gravity you can calculate the moment of inertia with respect to a new axis.

you need to be **careful** about the order to rotation and parallel translation though.